# What is the equivalent Tomcat setup to this Resin configuration?

Tags: tomcat, java, resin

The Resin configuration (`resin.xml`) pasted below achieves the following:

1. Binds the built-in http server to port 8000
2. Sets the desired maximum memory allocation (`-Xmx512m`)
3. Configures the webapp /path/web/root accessible from `http://domain.com` and `http://(www|www1|www2).domain.com`
4. Sets up access logging to /path/to/logs/access.log

This is the Resin configuration:

```
<resin>
  <cluster id="app-tier">
    <server-default>
      <!-- #1 -->
      <http port="8000"/>
      <!-- #2 -->
      <jvm-arg>-Xmx512m</jvm-arg>
    </server-default>
    <!-- #3 -->
    <host id='domain.com' root-directory="/path/web/root">
      <web-app id="/" />
      <!-- #3 -->
      <host-alias-regexp>(www|www1|www2).domain.com</host-alias-regexp>
      <!-- #4 -->
      <access-log path="/path/to/logs/access.log" />
    </host>
  </cluster>
</resin>
```

I'm switching from Resin to Tomcat and my question is hence:

- What is the "best practice configuration" for Tomcat to achieve the four things outlined above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer *some* of these questions.

Changing the port number is done by editing the appropriate `<Connector />` element in the `conf/server.xml` file (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html for more information).

Here is what comes out of the box:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

You could change the `port` attribute to anything you want.

Changing the heap size, or any other JVM setting, can be done using the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.  For example, you could add the following to `bin/startup.sh`:

```
# Must go *before* the final line ("exec ...")
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx512m"
```

I have never set up an access log before.  However, it **looks** like you can do it by un-commenting the appropriate "Valve" in `conf/server.xml` (see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html for details).

Example of the commented-out valve from my `server.xml` file:

```
<!-- Access log processes all example.
     Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
-->
```

Lastly, for virtual hosts, I can only point you to the documentation, which is at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html.  I hope this is better than nothing :-).